# Accessing super(parent) class variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am new to python. Im trying to access the parent class variable in child class using super() method but it throws error "no arguments". Accessing class variable using class name works but i like to know whether it is possible to access them using super() method.

```
class Parent(object):
        __props__ = (
            ('a', str, 'a var'),
            ('b', int, 'b var')
        )

        def __init__(self):
            self.test = 'foo'

class Child(Parent):
    __props__ = super().__props__ + (
        ('c', str, 'foo'),
    ) # Parent.__props__


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Error:

```
    __props__ = super().__props__ + (
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

Comment: I can't see what you are trying to do here. `super()` is something you call in an instance method, not at class level. And you shouldn't define your own double-underscore attributes anyway.

Comment: In python 3, classes by default derive from `object` so you can simply remove `object`; in regards to the issue; you're trying to use `super()` in a class top level definition; which can't be done.

Comment: @DanielRoseman To  make code more maintainable, for example in case i want to change the base type’s name. When using super everywhere, you just need to change it in the class line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an `__init_subclass__` method of the `Parent` class that initializes `Child.__props__`.  This method is called every time a subclass of of `Parent` is created, and we can use it to modify the `__props__` that class inherits with an optional `__props__` argument passed as part of the class definition.

```
class Parent:
    __props__ = (('a', str, 'a var'), ('b', int, 'b var'))
    def __init_subclass__(cls, __props__=(), **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.__props__ = cls.__props__ + __props__

class Child(Parent, __props__=(('c', str, 'foo'),)):
    pass

print(Child.__props__)
# (('a', <class 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <class 'int'>, 'b var'), ('c', <class 'str'>, 'foo'))

class GrandChild(Child, __props__=(('d', float, 'd var'),)):
    pass

print(GrandChild.__props__)
# (('a', <class 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <class 'int'>, 'b var'), 
#  ('c', <class 'str'>, 'foo'), ('d', <class 'float'>, 'd var'))
```

Answer (score 4):

`super` helps you get the parent class when you have an instance of it. As far as I know, there's no easy way to do this at the class level without an instance, like you're trying to do. The only way I could think of to do this is to refer to the parent class explicitly:

```
class Child(Parent):
    __props__ = Parent.__props__ + ...
```

To clarify a bit further, there's two basic problems:

- `super()` is syntactic sugar for `super(Child, self)`, or more generally, `super(type(self), self)`. Since there is no `self` where you're using it, it doesn't make sense.
- Even the class `Child` doesn't exist at the point that `super()` is getting called. It's still in the process of being defined, and so it would be invalid syntax to even have `super(Child, self)` (go ahead and try it, I can wait), because `Child` isn't a thing yet.

As such, you'll need to explicitly refer to the parent class, like I show above.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party but this is a job for [metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python):

```py
class Parent(object):
    __props__ = (
        ('a', str, 'a var'),
        ('b', int, 'b var')
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'foo'

class AddPropsMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls.__props__ = sum((base.__props__ for base in bases), ()) + cls.__props__
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class Child(Parent, metaclass=AddPropsMeta):
    __props__ = (
        ('c', str, 'foo'),
    )
```

```py
>>> Child.__props__
(('a', str, 'a var'), ('b', int, 'b var'), ('c', str, 'foo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__new__` method to change attributes of the parent class.

```
class Parent(object):
    __props__ = (
        ('a', str, 'a var'),
        ('b', int, 'b var')
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'foo'


class Child(Parent):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        parent = super(Child, cls)
        cls.__props__ = parent.__props__ + (('c', str, 'foo'),)
        return super(Child, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

p = Parent
print(p.__props__)
c = Child()
print(c.__props__)
```

**Output:**

```
(('a', <type 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <type 'int'>, 'b var'))
(('a', <type 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <type 'int'>, 'b var'), ('c', <type 'str'>, 'foo'))
```

At the same time be aware of this:

```
print(p.__props__)
c = Child
print(c.__props__)
c = Child()
print(c.__props__)
c = Child
print(c.__props__)
```

Output:

```
(('a', <type 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <type 'int'>, 'b var'))
(('a', <type 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <type 'int'>, 'b var'))
(('a', <type 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <type 'int'>, 'b var'), ('c', <type 'str'>, 'foo'))
(('a', <type 'str'>, 'a var'), ('b', <type 'int'>, 'b var'), ('c', <type 'str'>, 'foo'))
```

The `__props__` will change only after the first instantiation of your `Child` class.

Comment: As you point out yourself, initializing class properties in the constructor gives you results that don't really fit problem. Why would you recommend this approach at all?

Comment: The question was, if it is possible to access and modify class attributes with 
 `super()`. From the example it is not clear for me, how the attribute is used, whether it has to be modified before instantiating the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you write the super you use the Parent class name only.

```
class Parent:
        __props__ = (
            ('a', str, 'a var'),
            ('b', int, 'b var')
        )

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'foo'


class Child(Parent):
    __props__ = Parent.__props__ + (
        ('c', str, 'foo'),
    ) # Parent.__props__


    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__()
```

Hope It's useful. Thank you.