# Difference between invoking parent class via super vs the parent class name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the code:

```
class Mother(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._haircolor = "Brown"

class Child(Mother):
    def __init__(self): 
        #Mother.__init__(self)
        super(Mother, self).__init__(self)

    def print_haircolor(self):
        print self._haircolor

c = Child()
c.print_haircolor()
```

Why does `Mother.__init__(self)` work fine (it outputs `Brown`), but `super(Mother, self).__init__(self)` give the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    c = Child()
  File "test2.py", line 8, in __init__
    super(Mother, self).__init__(self)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I've seen [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/how-to-invoke-the-super-constructor), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189980/accessing-superparent-class-variable-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413670/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-parent-class-name), but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#super), The super object is bound to its second argument - so I imagine that under the hoods it is passing `self` to the method and you do not need to pass it again.

Comment: If possible, you should switch to Python 3.  https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two related issues.

First, as the error states, `object.__init__()` takes no arguments, but by running `super(Mother, self).__init__(self)`, you're trying to pass in an instance of `Child` to the constructor of `object`. Just run `super(Mother, self).__init__()`.

But second and more importantly, you're not using `super` correctly. If you want to run the constructor of the `Mother` class in `Child`, you need to pass in the subclass `Child`, not the superclass `Mother`. Thus, what you want is `super(Child, self).__init__(self)`.

When these fixes are added to your code, it runs as expected:

```
class Mother(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.haircolor = "Brown"

class Child(Mother):
    def __init__(self): 
        super(Child, self).__init__()

    def print_haircolor(self):
        print self.haircolor

c = Child()
c.print_haircolor() # output: brown
```